# On a menu of a restaurant there are $4$ types of meat. How many ways a client can eat $7$ pieces of the meat on the menu?

Tags: combinatorics

(a) 80
(b) 100
(c) 120
(d) 180

Initially I thought it would be a simple $C^7_4$ combination but it wasn't, I think I counted too much and tried to get the repetitions out, but I couldn't identify them. So I figured that for each meat I would have seven ways to eat but I would be counting too much again. The problem is to remove the repetitions. None of my answers got close to the alternatives. Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the number of pieces of meat-1, meat-2, meat-3  and meat-4 ordered be $x,y,z$ and $w$ respectively.

So we have: $$x+y+z+w=7$$

The Non-Negative Integral Solutions of this eqn would give us the required answer.Use the false-coin method to solve this.

[image]

Now, I introduce 3 false coins that are identical to the other coins.

[image]

The interesting thing is that... number of ways of choosing any three coins gives us the non-negative integral solutions of the above equation as it divides the total set into 4 parts. For instance if you choose the following coins:

[image]

Then we have the solution as $(2,2,2,1)$. So 2 pieces of meat-1, 2 of meat-2, 2 of meat-3, and 1 of meat-4

If you choose the coins like this:

[image]

Then your solution would be $(1,3,0,3)$.

Evidently, all ways of choosing 3 coins from the 10 coins gives us the total possible ways of ordering the meat. Hence total number of ways are$$^{7+3}C_3 = ^{10}C_3 =120$$

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

If the order of having the meat is not significant.

Then, it is about in how many ways for four types of meat summing up equals 7.

The answer is $\binom{7+3}{3}$.