# Integer solutions in an equation

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, diophantine-equations

Find how many integer solutions has the equation

$$1.\ \  x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 100;\  x_1 ≥ 0;\  x_2 ≥ 0;\  x_3 ≥ 0;$$

$$2.\ \  x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 100;\  x_1 ≥ 0;\  x_2 ≥ 30;\  10 ≤ x_3 ≤ 20.$$

Comment: Any thoughts? Ideas? Please try to write.

Comment: The first one, you can solve with the stars-and-bars method.

Comment: Do you have any knowlegde of distribution of alike objects ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first problem, refer [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3829306/823370)

Using the method mentioned above I am going to outline how you may approach the problem.

First give $30$ coins to to $x_2$ and $10$ coins to $x_3$. Now you have $60$ coins left. Find the NNIS (Non-negative integral solutions) to $$x_1+x_2'+x_3'=60$$

This gives you the cases where $x_1\geq0,x_2\geq30,x_3\geq10$

This also contains the cases where $x_3$ gets more than $20$ coins. So we need to calculate the unfavourable cases to subtract them from the total cases to get the answer. The unfavorable cases will be when $x_3$ gets $21$ or more coins. Evidently, the NNIS of
$$x_1+x_2'+x_3''=49$$
Represents those cases.

Finally, *Total cases - Unfavourable cases = Favourable Cases*