# When should one use the stars and bars method for combinatorics?

Tags: combinatorics

I find it hard to tell when certain methods/techniques for combinatorics questions should be used. I wonder if there is already a thread somewhere that compiles a list of all combinatorics techniques and when to use them? I'm also curious as to if there are any other uncommon "tricks" (like the stars and bars method) that one should know.

Comment: The stars and bars model is by no means uncommon; it’s also part of the repertoire of basic tools, so while it isn’t quite so straightforward as the multiplication principle, say, it’s really not a trick.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3829306/823370 Demonstrates another analogy of the stars and bars method. This might help you to gain some intuition for it. And regarding the other techniques, practice is the key.

Comment: A basic answer is that you can use the stars and bars technique to find the number of solutions to $x_1 + \cdots + x_m =n$, where each $x_i$ is restricted to be a nonnegative integer. You can also use it to solve problems which are equivalent to that problem, such as how many ways are there to distribute $n$ identical candies to $m$ kids.